# SQL Delete for each unique value in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach

I have a SQL query that joins two tables (messages  and meta) and then deletes from messages depending on the value of one of the columns, sender_id.  In the example below, I used the id of one user, 22.  How can I make this query loop through each unique value for sender_id?

```
DELETE `messages`
FROM
  `messages` LEFT JOIN `meta` ON (`meta`.message_id = `messages`.id) 
WHERE 
  `meta`.message_id IS NULL
AND 
  `messages`.date_sent < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) 
AND 
  `messages`.sender_id = 22 // How can I replace '22' so that the query searches for 
                               each unique value of sender_id?
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: If you want to delete rows for all senders you don't need that condition at all, simply remove it.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just leave the condition out?

```
DELETE m
FROM messages LEFT JOIN
     meta
     ON meta.message_id = m.id
WHERE m.message_id IS NULL AND 
      m.date_sent < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) ;
```

This will delete all messages that meet the condition.

Comment: Wow, so simple that it didn't cross my mind.  Thats what happens when you focus on something for so long and forget to think outside the box.  I'll accept your answer soon.  Thank you.